# Why do I have to explicitly call Show() after changing a boolean in Navigation.RegisterLocationChangingHandler?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, devexpress-blazor

This is for a Blazor server app using the DevExpress DxPopup component. But I don't think the specific component is at issue here.

I am checking to see if an EditForm has dirty values, and if so, then asking the user are they sure they want to discard the entered data. I set this up with:

```
registration = Navigation.RegisterLocationChangingHandler(OnLocationChanging);
// lots of code
private ValueTask OnLocationChanging(LocationChangingContext context)
{
    // if we have unsaved changes, prevent the navigation.
    if (_hasUnsavedChanges)
    {
        PopupDiscardVisible = true;
        DiscardPopup.ShowAsync();
        context.PreventNavigation();
    }

    return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
}
```

And over in the razor file:

```
<DxPopup @bind-Visible="@PopupDiscardVisible" @ref="DiscardPopup"
```

Here's my question. If I don't have the call to [DiscardPopup.ShowAsync()](https://docs.devexpress.com/Blazor/DevExpress.Blazor.DxPopupBase.ShowAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken)) then the popup does not show until something else causes the page to update/repaint.

Obviously this method exists for this very reason. But why? Shouldn't `PopupDiscardVisible = true` cause Blazor to refresh the page? Clearly there's something about when Blazor refreshes and how that I don't understand.

Comment: I suspect setting the value and then calling `StateHasChanged` probably will display the form as you expect.  This is generally true in Blazor: if you expect something to to change and it doesn't, you likely need to let Blazor know that you want the update.

Answer (score 0):

The Navigation Manager `OnLocationChanging` *event* is not a UI event, and therefore not handled by the `ComponentBase` UI event handler.  There's no calls to `StateHasChanged`.

`PopupDiscardVisible = true;` does just what it says, it mutates the state of the component.  There's no magic that detects component state mutation and triggers a call to `StateHasChanged` unless you code it.  Without a Render event, `ParamnmeterSetAsync` doesn't get called on `DxPopup` and it doesn't know about the mutation.

However, in this specific case, you can wire it up differently.  The `NavigationLock` component exposes the same functionality through `OnBeforeInternalNavigation` which is a component callback, and therefore a UI event that's handled by the `ComponentBase` UI event handler.

```cs
<NavigationLock OnBeforeInternalNavigation=this.OnLocationChanging ConfirmExternalNavigation=_isDirty />
```

You can see it used in my answer to your other question - [How do I asynchronously accept a Navigation.RegisterLocationChangingHandler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76086410/how-do-i-asynchronously-accept-a-navigation-registerlocationchanginghandler)

PS  There's a lot to learn about components and their behaviour: I've been coding them for over two years now.  It's all logical when you have gleaned and assimilated the necessary knowledge!

Comment: To your PS, I agree. But God is in the details. It's a long slow effort to learn all those details.

Comment: Most articles out there just regurgitate the same MS Documents stiuff, but there are some written by more knowledgeable people that go into greater depth.   There are some of mine on Code Project.  I learnt a lot by studying and understanding every line of code in `ComponentBase` - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Components/src/ComponentBase.cs.  And ask away on here.

Comment: I got an answer from DevExpress. The value of ShowAsync() is two-fold. First, StateHasChanged() re-renders everything while ShowAsync() just renders the popup. Second, ShowAsync() ignores the DxPopup.Visible value. Thanks again for the help.