# How do I asynchronously accept a Navigation.RegisterLocationChangingHandler?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Blazor server app. I want to ask the user if they're sure they want to leave a page if it has edited values. To do this I do the following:

```
    registration = Navigation.RegisterLocationChangingHandler(OnLocationChanging);
    // ... lots of code
    private ValueTask OnLocationChanging(LocationChangingContext context)
    {
        // if we have unsaved changes, prevent the navigation.
        if (_hasUnsavedChanges)
        {
            PopupDiscardVisible = true;
            DiscardPopup.ShowAsync();
            context.PreventNavigation();
        }
    
        return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
    }
    void DiscardChanges()
    {
        _hasUnsavedChanges = false;
        PopupDiscardVisible = false;
    }
```

The `DiscardPopup.ShowAsync()` pops up a window asking the user. But it pops it up asynchronously. So when `DiscardChanges()` is called, I've left the call `OnLocationChanging()`. So how do I now go to the url the user wants to go to?

And/or is there a way to put up a message box synchronously and get the Yes/No returned while still in `OnLocationChanging()`? Because this is a case where a synchronous prompt makes sense?

Comment: Can't you `await` the call to `DiscardPopup.ShowAsync();`?  Even with that I don't see the logic.  you will always prevent navigation because the next line is `context.PreventNavigation()`: there's no conditional check.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Yeah at present it prevents navigation because I have not yet received a Yes/No from the user.

Comment: See my second answer.  I had a quick look at the DX documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `NavigationLock` component directly in your form.

Here's a simple one page demonstration of linking the `NavigationLock` component into form state to control navigation.

```cs
@page "/"
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div class="m-2 p-3">
    <button class="@_buttonCss" @onclick=this.ToggleDirty>@_buttonText</button>
</div>

<div class="text-end">
    @if (_confirmExit)
    {
        <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick=this.Exit>Confirm Exit</button>
        <button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick=this.CancelExit>Cancel Exit Request</button>
    }
    else
    {
        <button disabled="@(!_isDirty)" class="btn btn-success" @onclick=this.Save>Save</button>
        <button hidden="@(!_isDirty)" class="btn btn-danger" @onclick=this.ConfirmExit>Exit without Saving</button>
        <button hidden="@(_isDirty)" class="btn btn-dark" @onclick=this.Exit>Exit</button>
    }

</div>

<NavigationLock OnBeforeInternalNavigation=this.OnLocationChanging ConfirmExternalNavigation=_isDirty />


@code {
    private bool _isDirty;
    private bool _confirmExit;
    private string _buttonText => _isDirty ? "Set Form To Clean" : "Set Form To Dirty";
    private string _buttonCss => _isDirty ? "btn btn-danger" : "btn btn-success";

    private void ToggleDirty()
        => _isDirty = !_isDirty;

    private void Save()
        => _isDirty = false;

    private void Exit()
    {
        _isDirty = false;
        NavManager.NavigateTo("/Counter");
    }

    private void ConfirmExit()
        => _confirmExit = true;

    private void CancelExit()
        => _confirmExit = false;

    private void OnLocationChanging(LocationChangingContext context)
    {
        if (_isDirty)
            context.PreventNavigation();
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Having now seen your other question this answer may not fit with DevX.  I'll leave it up as others may come here and find it useful.

Comment: You're using the browser message box instead of creating a custom popup - correct? I think that's the only way to prompt the user for a redirect to another site. But I'd prefer to use the DevExpress DxPopup for the popup for an internal redirect to stick with the site styling.

Comment: I'm using the built in box for navigating off site which is the only cross browser way to do it.  I'm not using any popup for the in site navigation, just hiding/showing buttons in the editor button bar.  I've changed direction on how to handle this situation several times over time.  It wasn't this easy pre Net7.0!

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

I don't use DX, but their popup show and hide probably works the same as others.

```cs
    private async ValueTask OnLocationChanging(LocationChangingContext context)
    {
        // if we have unsaved changes, popup and ask the question.
        if (_hasUnsavedChanges)
        {
            // You probably don't need to set PopupDiscardVisible if you're calling ShowAsync
            await DiscardPopup.ShowAsync();
            // code will yield and await the popup being closed by calling `CloseAsync`
        }
        // The user has now closed the popup so do what he requests
        if (_hasUnsavedChanges)
            context.PreventNavigation();
    }

    // Assume you call this from a button in the popup 
    private async Task DiscardChanges(bool value)
    {
        _hasUnsavedChanges = !value;
        await DiscardPopup.HideAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with Blazor Server (or any frameworks that rely on server-side rendering). There are certain events (such as key pressed) that cannot be effectively intercepted since every request is asynchronous.
I would suggest you use JSInterop and let Javascript on the page handle this scenario.